# Change color Title from a page sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, modern-pages, sitepages

So I'm trying to change this page Title Color

[image]

Every time I put a background image the title goes white, but I need this still black, have some way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

This is the default behavior in SharePoint online modern experience.

Page Title will be shown in Black color while using "Plain" or "Overlap" page layout.

And Page Title will be shown in White color while using "Image and title" or "Color block" page layout

So, to show the page title in black color, use either "Plain" or "Overlap" page layout.

[image]

---

You might be able to inject the custom CSS/JavaScript and change the page color using DOM manipulation. But, it is not recommended by Microsoft and DOM manipulation can break in future if Microsoft changes DOM element id/classes in future updates.